# How to extract a filename from a complex string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have a PHP string that contains a complex structure.
This is the string:

```
a:10:{s:4:"type";s:9:"image/png";s:5:"title";s:19:"1394228903_imac.png";s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/quote/1/3/2b2a7355414ba6d486a4fdd2af96809e.png";s:10:"order_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/order/1/3/2b2a7355414ba6d486a4fdd2af96809e.png";s:8:"fullpath";s:107:"/Users/Gabriel/Documents/Projects/demo4/media/custom_options/quote/1/3/2b2a7355414ba6d486a4fdd2af96809e.png";s:4:"size";s:4:"3558";s:5:"width";i:128;s:6:"height";i:128;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"2b2a7355414ba6d486a4";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:2:"42";s:3:"key";s:20:"2b2a7355414ba6d486a4";}}}
```

The string is stored in the `$fullValue` variable.

How can extract the image filename from there?
Specifically i want to extract this: `2b2a7355414ba6d486a4fdd2af96809e.png`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure you show here isn't a `json` string.
It looks like a serialized `php` string.

So, you should do this:

```
$data = unserialize($input);
echo basename($data["fullpath"]);
```